# How do I convert this list of dictionaries into a dictionary?

Tags: python

I am trying to convert this list, which contains dictionaries, into a dictionary.
From this list I am interested in taking out the **PREDICTION** column, since it contains another dictionary and to dump **PREDICTION** in a .csv with rows and columns.

Full data set here:

```
[{'origen': {'productor': 'AGENCY', 'site': 'www.example.com', 'link': 'www.example.com, 'language': 'en', 'copyright': 'YES', 'law': 'Example'}, 'creation_date': '2018-12-06', 'Name': 'UK', 'city': 'londo', 'PREDICTION': {'dia': [{'probPrecipitacion': [{'value': 0, 'periodo': '00-24'}, {'value': 0, 'periodo': '00-12'}, {'value': 0, 'periodo': '12-24'}, {'value': 0, 'periodo': '00-06'}, {'value': 0, 'periodo': '06-12'}, {'value': 0, 'periodo': '12-18'}, {'value': 0, 'periodo': '18-24'}], 'cotaNieveProv': [{'value': '', 'periodo': '00-24'}, {'value': '', 'periodo': '00-12'}, {'value': '', 'periodo': '12-24'}, {'value': '', 'periodo': '00-06'}, {'value': '', 'periodo': '06-12'}, {'value': '', 'periodo': '12-18'}, {'value': '', 'periodo': '18-24'}], 'estadoCielo': [{'value': '', 'periodo': '00-24', 'descripcion': ''}, {'value': '', 'periodo': '00-12', 'descripcion': ''}, {'value': '11', 'periodo': '12-24', 'descripcion': 'Despejado'}, {'value': '', 'periodo': '00-06', 'descripcion': ''}, {'value': '11', 'periodo': '06-12', 'descripcion': 'Despejado'}, {'value': '11', 'periodo': '12-18', 'descripcion': 'Despejado'}, {'value': '11n', 'periodo': '18-24', 'descripcion': 'Despejado'}], 'viento': [{'direccion': '', 'velocidad': 0, 'periodo': '00-24'}, {'direccion': '', 'velocidad': 0, 'periodo': '00-12'}, {'direccion': 'C', 'velocidad': 0, 'periodo': '12-24'}, {'direccion': 'C', 'velocidad': 0, 'periodo': '00-06'}, {'direccion': 'C', 'velocidad': 0, 'periodo': '06-12'}, {'direccion': 'C', 'velocidad': 0, 'periodo': '12-18'}, {'direccion': 'NE', 'velocidad': 5, 'periodo': '18-24'}], 'rachaMax': [{'value': '', 'periodo': '00-24'}, {'value': '', 'periodo': '00-12'}, {'value': '', 'periodo': '12-24'}, {'value': '', 'periodo': '00-06'}, {'value': '', 'periodo': '06-12'}, {'value': '', 'periodo': '12-18'}, {'value': '', 'periodo': '18-24'}], 'temperatura': {'maxima': 14, 'minima': 4, 'dato': [{'value': 5, 'hora': 6}, {'value': 12, 'hora': 12}, {'value': 11, 'hora': 18}, {'value': 6, 'hora': 24}]}, 'sensTermica': {'maxima': 14, 'minima': 4, 'dato': [{'value': 5, 'hora': 6}, {'value': 12, 'hora': 12}, {'value': 11, 'hora': 18}, {'value': 6, 'hora': 24}]}, 'humedadRelativa': {'maxima': 95, 'minima': 60, 'dato': [{'value': 95, 'hora': 6}, {'value': 60, 'hora': 12}, {'value': 75, 'hora': 18}, {'value': 80, 'hora': 24}]}, 'uvMax': 2, 'fecha': '2018-12-06'}, {'probPrecipitacion': [{'value': 0, 'periodo': '00-24'}, {'value': 0, 'periodo': '00-12'}, {'value': 0, 'periodo': '12-24'}, {'value': 0, 'periodo': '00-06'}, {'value': 0, 'periodo': '06-12'}, {'value': 0, 'periodo': '12-18'}, {'value': 0, 'periodo': '18-24'}], 'cotaNieveProv': [{'value': '', 'periodo': '00-24'}, {'value': '', 'periodo': '00-12'}, {'value': '', 'periodo': '12-24'}, {'value': '', 'periodo': '00-06'}, {'value': '', 'periodo': '06-12'}, {'value': '', 'periodo': '12-18'}, {'value': '', 'periodo': '18-24'}], 'estadoCielo': [{'value': '11', 'periodo': '00-24', 'descripcion': 'Despejado'}, {'value': '11', 'periodo': '00-12', 'descripcion': 'Despejado'}, {'value': '11', 'periodo': '12-24', 'descripcion': 'Despejado'}, {'value': '11n', 'periodo': '00-06', 'descripcion': 'Despejado'}, {'value': '11', 'periodo': '06-12', 'descripcion': 'Despejado'}, {'value': '11', 'periodo': '12-18', 'descripcion': 'Despejado'}, {'value': '11n', 'periodo': '18-24', 'descripcion': 'Despejado'}], 'viento': [{'direccion': 'S', 'velocidad': 10, 'periodo': '00-24'}, {'direccion': 'S', 'velocidad': 10, 'periodo': '00-12'}, {'direccion': 'S', 'velocidad': 10, 'periodo': '12-24'}, {'direccion': 'N', 'velocidad': 5, 'periodo': '00-06'}, {'direccion': 'S', 'velocidad': 10, 'periodo': '06-12'}, {'direccion': 'C', 'velocidad': 0, 'periodo': '12-18'}, {'direccion': 'O', 'velocidad': 5, 'periodo': '18-24'}], 'rachaMax': [{'value': '', 'periodo': '00-24'}, {'value': '', 'periodo': '00-12'}, {'value': '', 'periodo': '12-24'}, {'value': '', 'periodo': '00-06'}, {'value': '', 'periodo': '06-12'}, {'value': '', 'periodo': '12-18'}, {'value': '', 'periodo': '18-24'}], 'temperatura': {'maxima': 14, 'minima': 2, 'dato': [{'value': 2, 'hora': 6}, {'value': 10, 'hora': 12}, {'value': 9, 'hora': 18}, {'value': 8, 'hora': 24}]}, 'sensTermica': {'maxima': 14, 'minima': 2, 'dato': [{'value': 2, 'hora': 6}, {'value': 10, 'hora': 12}, {'value': 9, 'hora': 18}, {'value': 8, 'hora': 24}]}, 'humedadRelativa': {'maxima': 90, 'minima': 55, 'dato': [{'value': 90, 'hora': 6}, {'value': 65, 'hora': 12}, {'value': 80, 'hora': 18}, {'value': 80, 'hora': 24}]}, 'uvMax': 2, 'fecha': '2018-12-07'}, {'probPrecipitacion': [{'value': 0, 'periodo': '00-24'}, {'value': 0, 'periodo': '00-12'}, {'value': 0, 'periodo': '12-24'}], 'cotaNieveProv': [{'value': '', 'periodo': '00-24'}, {'value': '', 'periodo': '00-12'}, {'value': '', 'periodo': '12-24'}], 'estadoCielo': [{'value': '12', 'periodo': '00-24', 'descripcion': 'Poco nuboso'}, {'value': '12', 'periodo': '00-12', 'descripcion': 'Poco nuboso'}, {'value': '12', 'periodo': '12-24', 'descripcion': 'Poco nuboso'}], 'viento': [{'direccion': 'C', 'velocidad': 0, 'periodo': '00-24'}, {'direccion': 'O', 'velocidad': 5, 'periodo': '00-12'}, {'direccion': 'C', 'velocidad': 0, 'periodo': '12-24'}], 'rachaMax': [{'value': '', 'periodo': '00-24'}, {'value': '', 'periodo': '00-12'}, {'value': '', 'periodo': '12-24'}], 'temperatura': {'maxima': 13, 'minima': 5, 'dato': []}, 'sensTermica': {'maxima': 13, 'minima': 5, 'dato': []}, 'humedadRelativa': {'maxima': 90, 'minima': 65, 'dato': []}, 'uvMax': 2, 'fecha': '2018-12-08'}, {'probPrecipitacion': [{'value': 0, 'periodo': '00-24'}, {'value': 0, 'periodo': '00-12'}, {'value': 0, 'periodo': '12-24'}], 'cotaNieveProv': [{'value': '', 'periodo': '00-24'}, {'value': '', 'periodo': '00-12'}, {'value': '', 'periodo': '12-24'}], 'estadoCielo': [{'value': '12', 'periodo': '00-24', 'descripcion': 'Poco nuboso'}, {'value': '12', 'periodo': '00-12', 'descripcion': 'Poco nuboso'}, {'value': '11', 'periodo': '12-24', 'descripcion': 'Despejado'}], 'viento': [{'direccion': 'C', 'velocidad': 0, 'periodo': '00-24'}, {'direccion': 'NE', 'velocidad': 5, 'periodo': '00-12'}, {'direccion': 'C', 'velocidad': 0, 'periodo': '12-24'}], 'rachaMax': [{'value': '', 'periodo': '00-24'}, {'value': '', 'periodo': '00-12'}, {'value': '', 'periodo': '12-24'}], 'temperatura': {'maxima': 15, 'minima': 4, 'dato': []}, 'sensTermica': {'maxima': 15, 'minima': 4, 'dato': []}, 'humedadRelativa': {'maxima': 95, 'minima': 65, 'dato': []}, 'uvMax': 2, 'fecha': '2018-12-09'}, {'probPrecipitacion': [{'value': 0}], 'cotaNieveProv': [{'value': ''}], 'estadoCielo': [{'value': '12', 'descripcion': 'Poco nuboso'}], 'viento': [{'direccion': 'NE', 'velocidad': 10}], 'rachaMax': [{'value': ''}], 'temperatura': {'maxima': 14, 'minima': 4, 'dato': []}, 'sensTermica': {'maxima': 14, 'minima': 4, 'dato': []}, 'humedadRelativa': {'maxima': 80, 'minima': 55, 'dato': []}, 'uvMax': 0, 'fecha': '2018-12-10'}, {'probPrecipitacion': [{'value': 5}], 'cotaNieveProv': [{'value': ''}], 'estadoCielo': [{'value': '17', 'descripcion': 'Nubes altas'}], 'viento': [{'direccion': 'C', 'velocidad': 0}], 'rachaMax': [{'value': ''}], 'temperatura': {'maxima': 12, 'minima': 3, 'dato': []}, 'sensTermica': {'maxima': 12, 'minima': 3, 'dato': []}, 'humedadRelativa': {'maxima': 95, 'minima': 60, 'dato': []}, 'fecha': '2018-12-11'}, {'probPrecipitacion': [{'value': 65}], 'cotaNieveProv': [{'value': '1700'}], 'estadoCielo': [{'value': '24', 'descripcion': 'Nuboso con lluvia'}], 'viento': [{'direccion': 'C', 'velocidad': 0}], 'rachaMax': [{'value': ''}], 'temperatura': {'maxima': 10, 'minima': 2, 'dato': []}, 'sensTermica': {'maxima': 10, 'minima': 2, 'dato': []}, 'humedadRelativa': {'maxima': 100, 'minima': 85, 'dato': []}, 'fecha': '2018-12-12'}]}, 'id': 28079, 'version': 1.0}]
```

Example dataset:

> [{'origen': {'productor': 'agency', 'site': 'www.example.com', 'link':
>   'www.example.com, 'language': 'en', 'copyright': 'yes', 'law':
>   'example'}, 'creation_date': '2018-12-06', 'Name': 'uk', 'city':
>   'london', 'PREDICTION': {'dia': [{'probPrecipitacion': [{'value': 0,
>   'periodo': '00-24'}, {'value': 0, 'periodo': '00-12'}, {'value': 0,
>   'periodo': '12-24'}, {'value': 0, 'periodo': '00-06'}, {'value': 0,
>   'periodo': '06-12'}, {'value': 0, 'periodo': '12-18'},  'id': 28079,
>   'version': 1.0}]

I'm trying to use pandas:

```
predictions = pd.DataFrame (dataset)
predictions ['prediction']
```

OUPUT:

> 0  [{'probPrecipitacion': [{'value': 0, 'periodo'...

I would like to load the result of OUPUT in rows and columns.

Comment: Please post a *minimal* example and the expected output that showcases the problem.

Comment: Both the full data set and the example dataset contain syntax errors and I won't search and fix them by hand just to be able to instantiate that dataframe...

Answer (score 0):

The example you posted is a big mess and very difficult to understand.

Here is a simple way to print your data and visualise it.

```
import pprint
myDataset = {} #insert your dataset into this
pprint.pprint(myDataset)
```

Looking at the dataset you provided, you should be able to access the Prediction via

```
pred = myDataset[0]['origen']['PREDICTION']
```

since the dict containing 'PREDICTION' is in the 1st element of the list, i.e, the 0'th index, your access it via `myDataset[0]` . This will give you the dict. Now you can access the dict. 'PREDICTION' is stored in the value of the key called 'origen', you access that via `myDataset[0]['origen']`. Now this again points to another dict, and now you can access the value of the key 'PREDICTION' via `myDataset[0]['origen']['PREDICTION']`. By now you should have a basic idea of how this works. Similarly, parse the value given by code and write it in a csv. There should be plenty of examples on how to write a csv file all over the internet. Here is an example snippet.

```
import csv
with open('mycsv.csv', 'w') as writeFile:
    writer = csv.writer(writeFile)
    writer.writerows(variable_containing_some_data)
```

I hope it helps.

## EDIT:

Parsing through predictions should give your something like this I suppose

```
parsed_data = [{'value': 0, 'periodo': '00-24'}, 
{'value': 0, 'periodo': '00-12'}, 
{'value': 0, 'periodo': '12-24'}, 
{'value': 0, 'periodo': '00-06'}]
```

Load into pandas dataframe using

```
predictions = pd.DataFrame(data=parsed_data)
```

if you `print(predictions)` it automatically make a row and column representation like this

```
  periodo  value
0   00-24      0
1   00-12      0
2   12-24      0
3   00-06      0
```

if you want more control over the column names, you can use

```
predictions = pd.DataFrame(data=parsed_data, columns=. ['periodo','value'])
```

now you can directly save the data into a csv using

```
export_csv = predictions.to_csv (r'mycsv', index = None, header=True)
```

Your csv will look like this

```
periodo,value
00-24,0
00-12,0
12-24,0
00-06,0
```

Comment: Thank you.

I almost got it.

The first dataset that I put, checking the data type returns a list type to me.

Now taking your example:

pred = dataset [0] ['PREDICTION']

print (type (pred))

It returns a dictionary.

Now I want to convert this dictionary into rows and columns. I'm trying with Pandas but I can not get the result I'm looking for:

df_pred = pd.DataFrame (pred)

Comment: `print (type (pred))` is ok, but I would suggest you better `pprint.pprint(pred)` to sanity check whether you are actually parsing your dataset correctly.